# Android: Read information from android.mms.ui.conversationcomposer

Tags: android, sms, mms

I have been looking for this answer for quite a long time and no where I find a solution. :( Please help me..

I am developing an application that reacts to hardware button press (through broadcast receiver). The user will click on this button with a message/conversation thread open. Now, all I need to do is to read the message details (like Message body, From, date, etc. ) And store the information in sdcard.

I know, we can read all the message in the inbox, also, I know that we can know which application is active at the moment. And if the application that is open is android.mms.ui.conversationcomposer, can I get the thread id which is being displayed?

Please help me.